# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.7

I tried to install a package

```
composer require vinkla/instagram php-http/message php-http/guzzle6-adapter
```

I kept getting

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details                          
Using version ^9.1 for vinkla/instagram                                                                       
Using version ^1.7 for php-http/message                                                                       
Using version ^2.0 for php-http/guzzle6-adapter                                                               
./composer.json has been updated                                                                              
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                        
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.                                    

  Problem 1                                                                                                   
    - nexmo/client 1.6.1 requires php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.                          
    - nexmo/client 1.6.1 requires php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.                          
    - nexmo/client 1.6.1 requires php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.                          
    - Installation request for nexmo/client (locked at 1.6.1) -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[1.6.1].          


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I am on

php --version

```
PHP 7.2.14-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2019 10:33:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.14-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravelcollective/remote": "5.7.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.3",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",
        "htmlmin/htmlmin": "^5.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "vinkla/instagram": "^8.0",
        "php-http/message": "^1.6",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~5.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.1",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.1",
        "filp/whoops" : "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [ "database" ],

        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Any things I should check to fix this issue ?

Comment: You should probably raise this as an issue in the git repository of the package.

Comment: @thefallen : I did that already (https://github.com/vinkla/instagram/issues/99) , but I want to check here also maybe someone might have seen this before on other Laravel packages.

Comment: have you tested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019830/4149098

Answer (score 3):

There are two common ways of requiring new packages into your project via Composer: updating `composer.json`, or using the command `composer require`. It looks like you're doing both here, and Composer is getting confused.

When you use `composer require`, Composer will usually use the latest version. You can see this line in your screenshot after the command:

> Using version **^2.0** for php-http/guzzle6-adapter

`^2.0` is conflicting with the Instagram package, which requires `^1.1`. You can solve this in one of two ways:

**1) Update composer.json manually**

Your `composer.json` with the version `^1.1` specified looks good, but you don't want to use the `composer require` command in order to install it. Instead, use `composer update`.

You can run `composer update` without any arguments, and it will both install any new packages and update any existing packages that have a new version available. This may not be what you want, so instead you can specify the packages you want to update. In this case, it's the ones you're installing:

```
composer update vinkla/instagram php-http/message php-http/guzzle6-adapter
```

**2) Be explicit with the version number in require command**

You can specify version requirements in `composer require` using the following syntax: `vendor/package:[version]` So, your command becomes:

```
composer require vinkla/instagram php-http/message php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this on some packages, based on your error, you can just specify the package version. This worked for me:

```
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.1
```