# crscheid/php-article-extractor issues while componsoe install

Tags: php, composer-php, article

I run this command:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require crscheid/php-article-extractor -vvv
```

Resolving dependencies through SAT

```
Dependency resolution completed in 0.044 seconds
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-scotteh$php-goose.json from cache
Reading /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-scotteh$php-goose.json from cache
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - crscheid/php-article-extractor 2.5.1 requires scotteh/php-goose dev-master -> satisfiable by scotteh/php-goose[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - crscheid/php-article-extractor 2.5 requires scotteh/php-goose dev-master -> satisfiable by scotteh/php-goose[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for crscheid/php-article-extractor ^2.5 -> satisfiable by crscheid/php-article-extractor[2.5, 2.5.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

But this package won't be installed because it requires bigger composer version, my version is

```
Composer version 1.10.24 2021-12-09 20:06:33
```

can i still install it on this version, any help?

Comment: `composer require crscheid/php-article-extractor --with-dependencies` might work for you, failing that just `--ignore-platform-reqs`.

Comment: --with-dependencies" option does not exist. 
and --ignore-platform-reqs didnt helped, i got the same issue

Comment: Composer should have a `--with-dependencies` but failing yours doesn't for whatever strange reason then manually install what it is trying to ask you to have. `composer require scotteh/php-goose` in this case.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade composer?

Comment: composer require scotteh/php-goose i run this but recive the same issue like in the tiket description

Comment: Does this answer your question? [but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019784/but-these-conflict-with-your-requirements-or-minimum-stability)

Comment: If that does not yet help, please open a bug ticket for the maintainer of `crscheid/php-article-extractor` to ask why he does not use a version constraint for a stable version of `scotteh/php-goose`

Comment: @Jaquarh your comment solved the issue, i run composer require scotteh/php-goose but i need to add dev-master and now it works, please post your answer as an post so i can vote it

Comment: Answer your own question with your exact steps to make it work to help future viewers, I couldn't try it locally because I didn't have the same composer version as you but glad you resolved it! Best of luck with your project. @ttyttt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Step 1:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require scotteh/php-goose dev-master
```

Step 2:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require crscheid/php-article-extractor
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).